# Access denied error connecting to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

When I try to run the php file which requires config.inc.php  on my explorer ,it returns an error :

Failed to connect to the database: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'Lemon'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Ads By Faster Light×

Also when I run the file : config.inc.php ,it returns the same error ..!
Here is my config.inc.php :

```html
<?php 

    // These variables define the connection information for your MySQL database 
    $username = "Lemon"; 
    $password = "23242342"; 
    $host = "localhost"; 
    $dbname = "webservice"; 

// UTF-8 is a character encoding scheme that allows you to conveniently store 
    // a wide varienty of special characters, like ¢ or €, in your database. 
    // By passing the following $options array to the database connection code we 
    // are telling the MySQL server that we want to communicate with it using UTF-8 
    // See Wikipedia for more information on UTF-8: 
    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8 
    $options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'); 
     
    // A try/catch statement is a common method of error handling in object oriented code. 
    // First, PHP executes the code within the try block.  If at any time it encounters an 
    // error while executing that code, it stops immediately and jumps down to the 
    // catch block.  For more detailed information on exceptions and try/catch blocks: 
    // http://us2.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php 
    try 
    { 
        // This statement opens a connection to your database using the PDO library 
        // PDO is designed to provide a flexible interface between PHP and many 
        // different types of database servers.  For more information on PDO: 
        // http://us2.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php 
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 
        // If an error occurs while opening a connection to your database, it will 
        // be trapped here.  The script will output an error and stop executing. 
        // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
        // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code 
        // (like your database username and password). 
        die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    } 
     
    // This statement configures PDO to throw an exception when it encounters 
    // an error.  This allows us to use try/catch blocks to trap database errors. 
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
     
    // This statement configures PDO to return database rows from your database using an associative 
    // array.  This means the array will have string indexes, where the string value 
    // represents the name of the column in your database. 
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
     
    // This block of code is used to undo magic quotes.  Magic quotes are a terrible 
    // feature that was removed from PHP as of PHP 5.4.  However, older installations 
    // of PHP may still have magic quotes enabled and this code is necessary to 
    // prevent them from causing problems.  For more information on magic quotes: 
    // http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php 
    if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') && get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
    { 
        function undo_magic_quotes_gpc(&$array) 
        { 
            foreach($array as &$value) 
            { 
                if(is_array($value)) 
                { 
                    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($value); 
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    $value = stripslashes($value); 
                } 
            } 
        } 
     
        undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_POST); 
        undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_GET); 
        undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_COOKIE); 
    } 
     
    // This tells the web browser that your content is encoded using UTF-8 
    // and that it should submit content back to you using UTF-8 
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 
     
    // This initializes a session.  Sessions are used to store information about 
    // a visitor from one web page visit to the next.  Unlike a cookie, the information is 
    // stored on the server-side and cannot be modified by the visitor.  However, 
    // note that in most cases sessions do still use cookies and require the visitor 
    // to have cookies enabled.  For more information about sessions: 
    // http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php 
    session_start(); 

    // Note that it is a good practice to NOT end your PHP files with a closing PHP tag. 
    // This prevents trailing newlines on the file from being included in your output, 
    // which can cause problems with redirecting users.

?>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged as android?

Comment: Probably the user Lemon either doesn't have permission to connect via localhost to the MySQL server or you've entered the password incorrectly. Are you able to connect via the command line client? It's possible you've changed the password for, say, user Lemon with host `%` which is not the same as `localhost`. Double-check the permissions you've granted.

Comment: If you are sure the user specified has the appropriate permissions, then you might be connecting to the wrong MySQL server. Check which port the server you want to connect to is running on. The default port is 3306 but there is a possibility that your server is running multiple instances of MySQL on different ports.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. In my case there were 2 instances of mysql running on two different ports. Phpmyadmin is configured to bind with port 3306 by default and the username and password you are providing might be for the mysql instance running on a different port.

To confirm this on linux do:

```
ps aux | grep mysqld
```

If you see two instances running then this solution might work :

Find config.inc.php file. Now change this line: 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1'; To $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1:';

You can use: netstat -tlpn | grep mysql 
To figure out the port number.